# issue selecting from many-to-many

Tags: mysql, sql

my db is very simple:

```
CREATE TABLE Account (
    accountId int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (accountId)
);

CREATE TABLE Manager (
    managerId int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (managerId)
);

CREATE TABLE ManagerAccount(
    id int not null auto_increment,
    managerId int not null,
    accountId int not null,
    primary key(id),
    foreign key(managerid) references Manager (ManagerID),
    foreign key(accountId) references Account (AccountID)
);
```

Now, when i return an account object to the user I need to pull all the account associated with specific account

So I did something like:

```
select m.name
from manager m
inner join ManagerAccount ma on m.managerId = ma.id
inner join Account a on ma.id = a.accountId
where a.accountId = 1;
```

but this does not give me the answer I want, I only get one manager name and there are 3 managers associated with accountId 1...

you can see here:

[image]

Comment: I don't see how the query you included in your question could have generated that output.  And output along those lines is precisely what I would expect from that join structure.

Comment: Show us the output you want, and include some sample data which generates that output.

Comment: I dont want one i want all the managers associates with this account, i get one instead of 3

Comment: `I get one instead of 3` <-- is this the current state of affairs, or is this what you want to happen?

Comment: @giorgiga's answer should do it. Also you don't really need an `id` column in `ManagerAccount` table. You can create a composite primary key (accountId,ManagerId)

Comment: @IrfanAshraf thanks buddy, i will do that :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
inner join ManagerAccount ma on m.managerId = ma.id
inner join Account a on ma.id = a.accountId
```

should be

```
inner join ManagerAccount ma on m.managerId = ma.managerId
inner join Account a on ma.accountId = a.accountId
```

Comment: how can I learn how this thing works? feels a bit like magic, i did learn about joins but this is a bit more complex :/ @giorgiga

Comment: You should read some guide on SQL :) the super-condensed version is: "think of all joins as cartesian products and of `on` clauses (plus join type) as filters on that product set": `from a inner join b on a.f = b.f` is the same as `from a cross join b where a.f = b.f` (right and left joins are slightly different)

Answer (score 0):

In your query, you have an foreign key relationship of ManagerAccount.accountId with Account (AccountID).
But you have mapped the primary key of ManagerAccount table with Account (AccountID).

```
SELECT 
    m.name
FROM
    Manager m
        INNER JOIN
    ManagerAccount ma ON m.managerId = ma.managerId
        INNER JOIN
    Account a ON ma.accountId = a.accountId
WHERE
    a.accountId = 1;
```